# Facing peer dependency errors for ngx-responsive after upgrading Angular from version 15 to 16

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade, angular-migration

Earlier version of Angular: 15.2.0 and Node: was 14.21.3

Now we are upgrading the Angular from 15.2.0 to 16.2.9 and we are facing many peer dependencies.

In our code we are using Angular Material, Bootstrap, RXjs, NGX-Slick-Carousel, FontAwesome etc.

Please find the below package.json for 16.2.9 your reference.

```
    {
  "name": "csclient-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production --output-hashing none",
    "build:dev": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --c=dev --aot",
    "build:test": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --c=test --aot",
    "build:stage": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --c=stage --aot",
    "build:prod": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --c=production --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.9",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "5.0.2",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.3.0",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.25.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.3.6",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "ng-starrating": "^1.0.20",    
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.20",
    "ngx-ellipsis": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-responsive": "^9.0.3",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tslib": "2.0.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "ajv": "8.12.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.9",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/html-to-pdfmake": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.136",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.25",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.19",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.2",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

We have executed below command for Angular Upgrade:

```
ng update @angular/cdk@16.2.9 @angular/cli@16.2.9 @angular/core@16.2.9 @angular/material@16.2.9 ngx-toastr@18.0.0 @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.9 @angular-eslint/schematics@16.3.0 ngx-bootstrap@11.0.2 ngx-slick-carousel@15.0.0 @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.14.0
```

For Angular 16.2.0 we are using Node version 18.13.0.

Now we are facing below issues after upgradation:
[image]

For ngx-respnsive we checked and got to know that latest version of ngx-responsive is 9.0.3 and that is not compatible with NG version 16. Same thing for ng-starrating.

Any leads/suggestions would be appriciated.